# Can I run Access 2016 and Access 2013 on the same Windows 10 computer?

Tags: windows, windows-10, troubleshooting, microsoft-access

> NOTE: I asked this same question on DBA.StackExchange
>   [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/146112/can-i-run-access-2016-and-access-2013-on-the-same-windows-10-computer),
>   but I
>       think the site is too new because not getting many responses.
>       Cross-posting (is that right term?) here to get more
>        visibility. Let me know if I need to close the one over there.
>
> I'm just not really sure the right place to put this.

### The Issue

This is really just a simple question: Can I run Access 2016 and Access 2013 on the same computer?

I currently am running Windows 10 and whenever I open an Access 2007-2013 format database in Access 2016 -- even though the database is already open -- a windows pops up that says "Installing Access 2013 please wait" (paraphrase).

It was suggested to run different versions of Access by putting one in a virtual machine. Well, I tried installing VVV (vagrant) on Windows 10 and *it wasn't as intuitive as the YouTube videos made it seem*.

### My Questions

1. Is it possible/common to run Access 2013 and Access 2016 (both cloud versions) on the same Windows machine?
2. If so, what is required?
3. Can I do it without conflict if I don't use a Virtual Machine?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: My experience up to office 2013 (not tried 2016 yet, but no reason to believe it is different) is that only only have one version of an office application installed at the same time. So no word 2000 and 2010, no access 2010 and 2013 etc etc. In this regard microsoft office really is badly desgined for use on windows platforms.

Comment: Please do **not** crosspost. See [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Install-and-use-different-versions-of-Office-on-the-same-PC-6ebb44ce-18a3-43f9-a187-b78c513788bf,

"In most cases you cannot run Office 2016 and Office 2013 on the same computer. The exception to this is if Office was installed using an MSI."

The page offers tips for running multiple Office versions on the same computer.

"Keep in mind that even if you follow these recommendations, you might still run into issues when you use two versions of Office on the same PC."

Comment: Thanks! I had read that post but somehow I missed that part -- or maybe I was just in denial hoping somebody had a workaround that they use all the time. I've marked your answer as correct.